# What is causing me to get this EmptyStackException?

Tags: java, stack, runtime-error, postfix-notation, infix-notation

My program takes a postfix expression and changes it to an infix expression.

I have included two reasons for error in the code which is if the program does not have enough operators and if the input is not a valid number or operator.

The errors are caught when I put in input that is not good, however, when putting correct input in the scanner it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at PostfixToInfix.change(PostfixToInfix.java:67)
    at PostfixToInfix.main(PostfixToInfix.java:27)
```

What needs to be changed in my code?
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class PostfixToInfix
{
    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        PostfixToInfix exp = new PostfixToInfix();
        Scanner stdin =new Scanner(System.in);


        try { 
        boolean inputNeeded = true;
        int value = 0;

        while(inputNeeded){
            System.out.print("Postfix : ");
            if(stdin.hasNextInt()){
                inputNeeded = false;
            }
            else{
                throw new Error("Not a number or valid operator");
            }
        }
            String pf = stdin.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
            System.out.println("Infix : "+exp.change(pf));

        } 
        catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            System.out.println("Too few operators to produce a single result.");
        }


    }

    static boolean isOperator(char c)
    {
        if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c =='/' || c == '^')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    boolean empty() //whether the stack is empty
    {
        return x == 0;

    } // end empty

    public String change(String pf)
    {
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < pf.length(); i++)
        {
            char z = pf.charAt(i);
            if(isOperator(z))
            {
                String x = s.pop();
                String y = s.pop();
                s.push("("+y+z+x+")");      
            }
            else
            {
                s.push(""+z);
            }

        }   
        return s.pop();
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the input `1 1 +`.

- The Scanner reads the `1` and stores it in `value`.
- The Scanner reads the remaining string and a modified version of it (`"1+"`) is stored in `pf`, which is passed as an argument to the `change` method.
- `charAt` returns the first character of `pf` (a `'1'`), `isOperator` returns false, and the else block executes, which pushes `"1"` to the Stack.
- `charAt` returns the second character of `pf` (a `'+'`), `isOperator` returns true, and the if block executes.
- `pop` is called once, removing the only element in the stack, `"1"`, and assigning it to `x`. The stack is now empty, and the second call to `pop` results in the `EmptyStackException`.

This is how to debug your code if your IDE does not have a debugger already. Through this, you should find that using `nextInt` is the issue, since only one number will be present in the remaining string when the if block is expecting two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97460/discussion-between-tnt-and-anderkat97).